# Is there a identd-like package in Ubuntu that supports IPv6?

Tags: ipv6

Of those identd daemons available in Ubuntu 10.04, can any of them be made to work with IPv6?

If so, a nudge in the right direction regarding how to configure the IPv6 support would be nice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`oidentd` supports ipv6, but said support doesn't seem to be documented very well (or, y'know, at all...).

After installing it, you'll need to edit `/etc/default/oidentd` and change this:

```
OIDENT_OPTIONS="-mf"
```

to this:

```
OIDENT_OPTIONS="-mf -a ::"
```

and restart it, then it should listen on all your interfaces (both IPv4 and IPv6).